# How to format a Column with date datatype to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am creating a new table and I need a column with datatype DATE to have format YYYY-MM-DD when the column is initialized. I have used the CHECK TO_DATE() but I am getting an error message, which could come from the way I am entering the value within the table?

I have tried my_date DATE CHECK (my_date = TO_DATE(my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(mytable_id VARCHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY
          my_date DATE NOT NULL
          CHECK (my_date = TO_DATE(my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('01','2019-09-28');
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

I expected my columns and rows but instead, it is giving me an error message ORA-01861: literal does not match the format string. I have tried several ways but nothing work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

In your schema `my_date` is already a date, you can't convert a date to date, this line has no sense:

```
my_date DATE NOT NULL
CHECK (my_date = TO_DATE(my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')));
```

You can write `to_date` to cast string to a date:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('01',TO_DATE('2019-09-28'));
```

You should to understand that Oracle doesn't store `date` in string format, Oracle stores `date` in an internal binary format, because this, you should to cast from string to the internal binary representation for `date`.

If you want to format date on output, the way is use [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm):

```
select to_char( my_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) as myFormatedDate
from my_table;
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked and I also found the ALTER SESSION statement which worked great as well. Thanks again

Comment: Using `TO_DATE('2019-09-28')` is risky as it depends on current user session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. Use either DATE literal `DATE '2019-09-28'` or specify the format explicitly `TO_DATE('2019-09-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`